# Decrypt HTTPS traffic and save clear traffic into a pcap file

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, wireshark

Wireshark could decrypt https and display clear text(http) to user, but Wireshark do not support save clear text into pcap file, the content in pcap file is still encrypted even I can see the decrypt info before saving. 
I'd like to know if there is a way to capture https traffic and save it into pcap file with http format?
Is it possible that setup a web proxy which can accepts SSL connections and forwards them over non-SSL, then use Wireshark to capture pcap at non-SSL side? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wireshark **can** decrypt SSL, if it has access to the master secret.  See [this answer on the information security part of the website](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites/42350) for how to configure wireshark.  I would advise to save both the SSL packets and the master secret, going through a decrypting proxy means tinkering with your capture. (although, definitely, it is possible to setup such a proxy)

Comment: Thanks grochmal. The solution of saving master secret is not suitable for my scenario. Could you please explain more about how to use proxy to do this?  I tried with some proxy tools, like MITMProxy and Fiddler, I don't know how to forward decrypt traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy) to intercept TLS traffic and save the decrypted data to a PCAP file.